# GIT PUSH - Is there any way to know which developer actually pushed a code?

Tags: git, push

Is there any way to know which developer actually pushed a code? 
I just merged from branch into another and pushed it. I didn't commit anything for branch. Just pushed. 
I can't see anything in the log that shows that I am the "pusher". 
What is the command to see in who made the "push" actually?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you're using some extras to log push / pull, committer and author is all you have. That said, a case where the last commit is not from the developer who pushed to the remote repository would be a bit weird (I think). Because only that developer could have been in possession of that commit (if he didn't somehow share it via USB stick or a different remote repository).

Comment: Thanks, but somethings developers push some unfinished code and we have no idea who pushed what...

Comment: +1 - But there's nothing weird. I think OP's case here is a fast-forward merge that he did, so that his push didn't introduce any new commits but only moved the master branch.

Comment: It is not weird, if the pushing developer had first pulled from another developer without going through the central repository.

Comment: @Nir Koren: Could you clarify if your devs have the possibility to pull from multiple repositories?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write server-side hook script for the extra logging purpose.
`.git/hooks/post-receive`

Comment: That would only work if every push / pull operation goes through exactly one remote repository. But as @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen points out, from the description it seems like there might be multiple repositories to pull from.

Comment: Set hook script to all remote repositories, if possible.

Comment: No good. You'd have to go through all the possible repositories and check the logs since they're not passed on in a pull (unless you store the log in the repository itself, which is ugly).

Comment: I am talk about using git-core alone. Otherwise, you have to install extra git management interfaces (such as gitlab, gitorious, ...) for this purpose.